# Is using aggregate rating structured data for every page considered spam?

Tags: seo, schema.org, structured-data, user-reviews

I am working on a new website. It's a website with videos. On every video page below the video frame the visitors will have the possibility to rate the video between 1 and 5 stars. The rating will be shown for each video.

If I implement schema.org aggregate rating structured data for every video page so that the search engine snippet will also display the rating and the number of votes, will that be considered spam?

Considering it's a videos website 99% of the pages will have this implemented, could this be considered spam?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that’s exactly the intended purpose of [`AggregateRating`](http://schema.org/AggregateRating).

If the video has a rating, there is no point in *not* providing the rating in structured data, too.

By using the [`itemReviewed`](http://schema.org/itemReviewed) property, it’s clear to which item the rating belongs, and consumers (like search engines) can decide if to do something with it.  For example, Google Search displays a ratings rich snippet only¹ for local businesses, movies, books, music, and products. But that doesn’t mean that you shouldn’t use the markup in your case; it means that you shouldn’t expect to see a rich result for it.

---

¹ At least according to their [*Review snippets* documentation](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/reviews#review-snippets). I think there are several cases where the snippet gets displayed for items in other categories, too.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. One thing that I want to do is to allow only logged in members to rate a video. The rating will be displayed for everyone but only members/logged in users will be able to rate. I presume this will not create any issues right ? Thank you again for your answer.

Comment: @ClawDuda: Should be fine (it’s probably done like that in most cases). Of course we don’t know how the consumer’s algorithms work for detecting if the content actually has/allows ratings, or if the author just "fakes" them. But even if a consumer can’t find the rating on the page, the worst that should happen is that no rich result gets displayed. -- But if you really display the rating result on the page, I think you have nothing to worry.